# asp:Image - tag in repeater

Tags: asp.net, image, repeater

Why does the second line work but not the first one?
I get the "The server tag is not well formed". 
And the Guid I've copy into the second line is directly from the database.

```
< asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Avatar/Avatar.aspx?UserId=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId")%>" />

< asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Avatar/Avatar.aspx?UserId=22AA736E-BD1B-4623-8E76-4769051F2E60" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try

```
< asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Images/Avatar/Avatar.aspx?UserId=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId")%>' />
```

Your problem was the double quotes. Your opening quote was a double quote so was being closed by the opening quote on "UserID".
You should also always use single quotes when databinding anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Put *single* quote around value of *ImageUrl* attribute.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" 
           ImageUrl='~/Images/Avatar/Avatar.aspx?
              UserId=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId")%>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use `String.Format(...)`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avatar" SortExpression="LastName, FirstName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Images/Avatar/Avatar.aspx?UserID={0}", Eval("UserID").ToString()) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing you `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId")%>` in a label. The way a Guid is formatted might not be exactly like what it looks like in the database. If i remeber correcctly, it might had {} around the Guid.